# Google App add contact error?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my GAE app there is the following line :

```
ContactsService myService=new ContactsService("app-name");
```

It compiled fine, but when run, it cause the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterators.forArray([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$ArrayImmutableSet.iterator(ImmutableSet.java:415)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$ArrayImmutableSet.iterator(ImmutableSet.java:392)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$Builder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:317)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$Builder.addAll(ImmutableList.java:601)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<init>(AltFormat.java:183)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<init>(AltFormat.java:42)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.build(AltFormat.java:457)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
    at Test.ContactsExample.<init>(ContactsExample.java:102)
```

I've included guava-r09.jar, so it has the "ImmutableSet", if I don't included guava-r09.jar, it will say :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why : don't need to include google-collect-*.jar, source of error.